# Hide a specific folder and it's sub folders and files ?

Tags: seo, robots.txt

I want to hide a folder named ( beta ) in the public_html from the search engines also all it's subfolders and files, do i have to put the file in the root folder ( / ) and do the content of the robots.txt like the following

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /public_html/beta
```

OR

put robots.txt in the public_html and do the content as the following

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /beta
```

Answer (score 2):

The robots.txt must be in the root.

www.yoursite.com/robots.txt

This is what you need:

User-agent: *

Disallow: /folder/something

With something being the name of the folder you want to disallow

Also, note that you only want to block the subfolder named something. If you also have a file named something that you don't want to disallow, than do this:

User-agent: *

Disallow: /folder/something/

Answer (score 0):

What matters is the public URL, not the actual physical folder of your server.

So when you have a site at `example.com/cooking/index.html`, your robots.txt needs to be at `example.com/robots.txt`. For `sports.example.com/football/blog` it would be `sports.example.com/robots.txt`.

Answer (score -1):

The best solution is to hide your all sub-folders and files from beta. You can define robots.txt as follows:

User-agent:  *

Disallow: /beta*/

Now, all search engines will not crawl all sub-directories and files followed by beta.